# How to set the foreign key in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query to create the primary key table is

```
create table Users
(
    Id int identity (3000, 1),
    UserId as '08U1'+right('0000'+cast(Id as varchar(5)), 5) persisted,
    UserName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    Location varchar(50),
    constraint PK_Users primary key (UserId)
)
```

And the reference table is

```
create table addre
(
    Ids int,
    address varchar(50),
)
```

I want to **UserId primary key** in the **Users table** to **reference table addre** column **Ids as foreign key** how to set that. I know that the **same data type** is only used to set foreign key. Where here how to set the data type for the Ids...

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you're trying to do. Can you add some sample data (for *both* tables) that shows some rows that should work with the foreign key and at least one row that should be rejected by the foreign key please?

Comment: why not change datatype to varchar of column Ids in addre table ?

Comment: Don't you mean table `addr` references `Users`? That is, `addr` has the foreign key to `Users`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change UserID to this

```
UserId as CAST('08U1'+right('0000'+cast(Id as varchar(5)), 5) AS char(9)) persisted
```

So `char(9)` is the datatype needed whichever way around you want

Comment: the foreign that has been created but it does not store the values of UserId in the Ids

Comment: A foreign key does not automatically populate. Ask another question with sample SQL and data